# How is Java 9 running code compiled with Java 8 that is using a non-exported package

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

I compiled following code using Java-8 compiler:

```
package pack;
import sun.util.calendar.CalendarUtils;
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(CalendarUtils.isGregorianLeapYear(2018));
    }
}
```

I compiled the above code using Java-8 compiler as:

```
gyan@gyan-pc:~/codes/java$ ~/Documents/softwares/Linux/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/javac -d . a.java
a.java:2: warning: CalendarUtils is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
import sun.util.calendar.CalendarUtils;
                        ^
a.java:9: warning: CalendarUtils is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
        System.out.println(CalendarUtils.isGregorianLeapYear(2018));
                           ^
2 warnings
```

Version of my default Java Interpreter:

```
gyan@gyan-pc:~/codes/java$ java -version
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

And I can run the compiled code using Java-9 interpreter without any error.

```
gyan@gyan-pc:~/codes/java$ java pack.a
false
```

**According to my knowledge:** At runtime the package "pack" will be contained inside a special module called "Unnamed module". The "Unnamed module" requires all the modules from Java platform module. But only that package can be used by the "Unnamed module" which are exported by the corresponding module.

**My question is:**
Here the module java.base is not exporting the package "sun.util.calendar". Then how the "Unnamed module" is using it?

Comment: All the details are in the "Relaxed-strong-encapsulation" section of JEP 261 (http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261#Relaxed-strong-encapsulation).

Comment: @AlanBateman Nice to know. I think I missed it while I read the JEP previously. Moreover, using `--illegal-access=warn` also doesn't generate a warning for the above-compiled code. Is that expected?

Comment: Yes, this is expected as "warn" is to emit warnings for reflective access only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [pointed by Alan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48420884/how-the-java-9-is-running-a-code-using-non-exported-package-compiled-by-java-8#comment83831793_48420884), the section [Relaxed strong encapsulation](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261#Relaxed-strong-encapsulation) states the following in this respect :-

> `--illegal-access=permit` **opens each package in each module in the run-time image to code in all unnamed modules**, i.e., to code on the
>   class path, if that package existed in JDK 8. *This enables both static
>   access, i.e., by compiled bytecode, and deep reflective access, via
>   the platform's various reflection APIs.*
>
> The first reflective-access operation to any such package causes a
>   warning to be issued, but no warnings are issued after that point.
>   This single warning describes how to enable further warnings. This
>   warning cannot be suppressed.
>
> This mode is the ***default in JDK 9***. It will be phased out in a future
>   release and, eventually, removed.

Also, if you try to execute the compiled code with

```
.../jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java --illegal-access=deny pack.Some
```

***using the future default*** flag, you wouldn't be able to execute the code as expected with the following trace :

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class
> pack.Some (in unnamed module @0x1055e4af) cannot access class
> sun.util.calendar.CalendarUtils (in module java.base) because module
> java.base does not export sun.util.calendar to unnamed module
> @0x1055e4af    at pack.Some.main(Some.java:7)
> ```